# Как отправить "PATCH" запрос с помощью fetch

Tags: javascript, json, fetch

Нужно отправить запрос на сервер для изменения данных - "PATCH" запрос,

```
fetch('http://localhost:3000/person/1', {"PATCH", body, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}})
```

Если я передаю какой либо body то появляется ошибка некорректного запроса. Если просто без body то он мне возвращает объект целиком .
Пример JSON :

```
{
"person": [
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Name",
  "icon": "icon",
  "message": [
    {
      "text": "message for other"
    },
    {
      "text": "message for me"
    }
  ]
},
 {
  "id": 2,
  "name": "Name2",
  "icon": "icon2",
  "message": [
    {
      "text": "message for other2"
    },
    {
      "text": "message for me2"
    }
  ]
}]}
```

Нужно изменить только поле message передав туда новый массив , как это сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно указать имя свойства в объекте и его имя

```
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1', {
  method: 'PATCH', // <--- имя запроса
  body: JSON.stringify(obj), // Тело 
  headers: {
    // Заголовки
  },
})
```

Comment: Не совсем понятно , что и куда нужно указать

Comment: Вполне всё понятно. В коде всё подписано

Comment: Все что вы написали у меня в коде и так есть , но при передаче body всё равно ошибка

Comment: "Все что вы написали у меня в коде и так есть" --- нет. сравни свой код с текущим...у тебя как минимум ошибка синтаксиса, так что не надо говорить про "так и есть"..........."но при передаче body всё равно ошибка" --- потому что ты пишешь не так, как написано в ответе

Comment: Извиняюсь , ошибка была в JSON.stringify(obj) , спасибо)

Comment: @SkyFull, `JSON.stringify(obj)` не единственная ошибка.